# How to call a JQuery function from a MVC controller

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Is there a way to run a jquery function from a MVC controller.  I have a computer running Windows 7 Embedded and uses a touch screen without a keyboard.  As part of the application, I need to copy files off of the computer.  In the MVC application, I have a file transfer razor view that I want to use to select the files to copy to the usb.  I have a event in the controller that fires an event (runs a c# method) when the usb is inserted or removed.  I would like this event method to enable a button on the view so the user can’t try to save files (the button will be disabled) until a usb is inserted.  I have the code to detect the usb insertion, determine the drive letter of the usb, but I can’t get it to enable the button.  If I could call a jquery function from the controller, I think I can use the function to enable the button.
I have looked at “Call Jquery function from a MVC Action” on stack overflow but they have the event triggered from a form.  I have an event triggered by the controller.
Is there a different / better way to enable the (save) button on a view when a usb drive is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new ActionResult method in your controller, which will render partial view that contains that button. So when usb is inserted, event is triggered, and in MVC controller RedirectToAction calls your new method that renders partial view with button.

Comment: I made a partial view with the button that should be enabled when the usb is inserted and disabled when it is removed.  The events are firing in the controller.  How do I enable or disable a view object from the controller?

Comment: You can make two partials view, first one that will be rendered when usb is inserted, and second one that will be rendered whed usb is removed. You can render partial view from controller:
return PartialView("view1.cshtml") or PartialView("view2.cshtml")
In view1 you can enable button, in view2 you can show disabled button

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could achieve this is by repeatedly calling a controller action through Ajax to find out if the usb is known to be available. Use setInterval to call a function every n seconds.

However, what happens when they pull it out?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I thought about trying this but was hoping for a different, event driven way to accomplish this.  I can tell when a Usb is inserted and I can tell when it is removed.  I just can't seem to run javascript code from the controller when this happens.